# responses back on email

Tags: php, email

it is such that I am working on a website to make Fire in my municipality

**the problem is that you can not reply back to the email as one of the users have to make it possible to get in with konakt.**

```
 <form action="#" method="post">
          <table>
             <tr>
                <td>Navn</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="navn" class="new"></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Efternavn</td>
                <td><input type="tel" name="efternavn" class="new" maxlength="8"></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input type="email" name="email" class="new"></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Tekst</td>
                <td><textarea name="tekst" cols="35" rows="10"></textarea></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" class="new"></td>
                <td></td>
             </tr>
          </table>
       </form>
       <?php
       if(isset($_POST["send"]))
       {
          $fra = $_POST["navn"] . $_POST["efternavn"] . " - <" . $_POST["email"] . ">";
          $email = "info@blablla.dk";
          $title = $_POST["navn"] . " Kontakt - Website";
          $tekst = $_POST["tekst"];

          //headers
          $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
          $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
          $headers .= "From: " . $fra . "";

          mail($email, $title, $tekst, $til);
          echo "den er sendt nu NY";
       }
       ?>
```

Here's how:

```
" - <" . $_POST["email"] . ">";
```

There will not show email that you have written in order to stand therefore in place for blabla@meebox.dk or look like in the still but I'd like it's him users who have written

Answer (score 0):

You can't define the `name of field` in the `type attribute of the field`.

```
 <form action="" method="post">
          <table>
             <tr>
                <td>Navn</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="navn" class="new"></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Efternavn</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="efternavn" class="new" maxlength="8"></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email" class="new"></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Tekst</td>
                <td><textarea name="tekst" cols="35" rows="10"></textarea></td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" class="new"></td>
                <td></td>
             </tr>
          </table>
       </form>
       <?php
       if(isset($_POST["send"]))
       {
          $fra = $_POST["navn"] . $_POST["efternavn"] . " - <" . $_POST["email"] . ">";
          $email = "info@blablla.dk";
          $title = $_POST["navn"] . " Kontakt - Website";
          $tekst = $_POST["tekst"];

          //headers
          $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
          $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8";
          $headers .= "From: " . $fra . "";

          mail($email, $title, $tekst, $til);
          echo "den er sendt nu NY";
       }
       ?>
```

Now try this and it will work.

Comment: What do you want to say, why it won't work. And to whom i show and show what?

Comment: What did u write into email field?

Comment: topic that's fine but at the link I posted which read "FRA" means in English "from". this is where the problem is. I would in fact like to have users email which when standing from

Comment: So in "FRA", you are getting user's email address. Don't u want email there? Just post an image of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to user can reply  your mail then you have to add this to your headers  code.

```
$headers = 'Reply-To: Your email address "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

This might be helps you.